# Approximations of continuous functions by compactly supported smooth functions with a criteria.

Tags: real-analysis, approximation, approximation-theory

Let $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^{\ge 0}$ be a bounded continuous function, where $\Omega$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove or reject (by providing a counterexample) that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a compactly supported smooth function $g :\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{\ge 0}$ with  $0\le f-g<\epsilon$.

When there exists $\delta>0$ with $f(x)>\delta$ for any $x$, a suitable $g$ could be found. Otherwise, I do not know how to use the famous approximation theorems to solve this problem.

Comment: Oops.. You are right, I edited the problem. About your answer, assume that for instance $g$ is a smooth function with $\lVert g-f\rVert_{\infty}<\epsilon$. Now, if for some $x_0$, $f(x_0)=0$, then how $g/2$ could be non-negative and less than $f$? In this situation, it is clear that $g(x_0)$ must be $0$. However, how Weierstrass approximation theorem guaranties this?

Comment: After your edits we have to be a bit more clever, but we can still do it. Uniformly approximate from below, eg consider $f - \epsilon/2$ and uniformly approximate via a function $g$ taking values in $\mathbb R$ to within $\epsilon / 2$. Now at any point where $g$ is negative we make it zero. There will be points of nonsmoothness where we transition to being zero, but we can just modify the function by an arbitrarily small amount in that region to fix things (you could formalize this by composing with mollifiers scaled by the right multiple of epsilon if you wish)

Comment: Thank you for your idea. However, mathematical details for modifying the function in the last step are not clear to me.

Comment: Let us assume that we have a continuous function $h$ with $0\le f-h<\epsilon$. Now, we want to find a smooth function $g$ (probably by modifying $h$) with $0\le f-g<\epsilon$. I do not have enough knowledge on mollifiers, but as I know, a mollifier for $h$ is $\Phi_{\epsilon}(h)(x)=\int \phi_{\epsilon}(x-y)g(y)\,dx$, where $\phi_{\epsilon}(x)=\epsilon^{-n}\phi(x/\epsilon)$ for which $\phi$ is for instance a bump function that is zero outside of a closed interval $J$. Now, if for instance $f(x_0)=0$, then we must have $g(x_0)=0$.

Comment: So, if $\Phi_{\epsilon}(h)$ is a candidate for $g$, then the above integral must be $0$, which implies that $h$ must be $0$ on $[x_0-\epsilon, x_0+\epsilon]$, while this might not be true! 
So, $\Phi_{\epsilon}(h)$ does not seem a suitable candidate for $g$. However, you have suggested a composition with a mollifier and then a scaling approach. Could you tell me what is the mollifier you considered?

Comment: Is there a missing assumption that $f$ is compactly supported, or at least vanishing at infinity?  Otherwise it's trivially false.

Comment: Thank you. I have missed an assumption. I edited the problem. Actually $\Omega$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @MathLover Convolution with a suitable mollifier (with arbitrarily small support) changes your values by an arbitrarily small amount but adds smoothness (we are working with a continuous function locally which can be viewed as a distribution so it works out). You can make yourself plenty of wiggle room by, for example, approximating $f - \epsilon/2$ within $\epsilon / 3$ (giving $\epsilon/6$ of wiggle room to mollify in, plenty to make the argument work out). The idea is to use continuity at every nonzero point to get an open set where it's nonzero and we can use the first argument I gave...

Comment: ... and then cutoff to zero around zero points and then use convolution via a mollifier around each to smooth it out and then use compactness to glue everything together.

Comment: This should at least work for continuous functions with countably many zeros, though the only case I think one should consider is for uncountably many zeros since I'd worry that uncountably many choices of epsilon would be too big for the compact set. An example of such a continuous function is the distance from a point to the cantor set

Comment: I think we avoid such problems because we really only need to mollify finitely many times to cover the entire set, since we can just choose a small enough mollification error (e.g. strictly within $\epsilon/6$ using what I noted above) and then just cover the set with finitely many such mollifications using compactness.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thank you so much! I will think about your idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $f$ is supposed to be compactly supported.

Start with a smooth function $g_1$ so that $|f-g_1| < \epsilon$ everywhere.  Let $g_2 = g-2\epsilon$, so that $\epsilon < f-g_2 < 3 \epsilon$ everywhere.  Now let $\psi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{\ge 0}$ be a smooth approximation of the "positive part" function, such that $\psi(x)=0$ for all $x \le 0$, and $|\psi(x) - x| < \epsilon$ for all $x \ge 0$.  Set $g_3 = \psi \circ g_2$ and note that $g_3 \ge 0$ everywhere.

Now consider two cases:

- if $g_2(x) \ge 0$, then $|g_3(x) - g_2(x)| < \epsilon$, so we have $0 < f(x)-g_3(x) < 4\epsilon$.
- if $g_2(x) < 0$, so that $g_3(x) = 0 > g_2(x)$, then $f(x) - g_3(x) < f(x) - g_2(x) < 4 \epsilon$, and since $f(x) \ge 0$, we still have $f(x) - g_3(x) \ge 0$.

If you want, go back and replace all $\epsilon$ by $\epsilon/4$.

Note that since $f$ is compactly supported, the inequality $0 \le g(x) \le f(x)$ implies that $g_3$ is too.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your solution is so wise and interesting. As I see now, in general  my statement is not true. Actually, one could assume that $\Omega=(0,1)$ and $f\equiv 1$. However, the following similar statement seems true to me: finding a compactly supported function $g$ with $0\le g\le f$ and $\int_{\Omega}|f-g|\,d x<\epsilon$.